# Alternative for MS Project not supporting ODBC

Tags: oracle, odbc, ms-project

Currently, we have an application that saves MS Project files into an Oracle DB using the ODBC datasource selection from within 2002 project.  The process works in reverse as well - accessing the file through the database to open.  We need to upgrade to Project version 2016 which I found no longer supports ODBC.  I have been unable to find any kind of alternative or work-around for this issue as I would like to continue to utilize the Oracle database as the repository.

Does anyone have any suggestions or know of any alternatives to continue to make this process from Project to Oracle using ODBC function?

Comment: According to this [Project 2016 and ODBC Connections to MySQL](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/981a37e3-1989-49f2-a258-e75229992760/project-2016-and-odbc-connections-to-mysql?forum=projectprofessional2010general) you would need to write some VB code. I am not familiar with MS Project, is there any possibility to connect to an external data source? - Maybe OLE DB?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make the switch to Project Online? For $30/mo you can get an account through Office 365, and you have full Project Server capability. From there you should be able to query the server as needed just like you would your Oracle repository. Or, go ahead and replicate it to your Oracle repository using REST queries:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163048.aspx

Comment: It's a Powerbuilder application that launches the call to MS Project, and the Project data is saved in the Oracle databas used in other places in the PB app.  The intent is to try to keep the project data in the Oracle DB.  REST queries can do this?

Comment: Should be able to make it work. But what about something like this: https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/msproject-jdbc-powerbuilder.rst

Answer (score 0):

You may find [MPXJ](http://mpxj.org) helpful. You'll need to manage storing the MPP file, but MPXJ will allow you to read the file each time it is updated to extract the attributes which are relevant to you, allowing you to populate your existing database.